# 2 ways of filtering pandas dataframes

Tags: pandas

In pandas(python 3), what is the difference between:

```
df_merged.loc[(df_merged['date1']==int(date_month))]
```

&

```
df_merged=df_merged[df_merged['date1']==int(date_month)]
```

The 2nd one works as expected, the first one selects all rows even if the condition is false.

Comment: hmmm, I think it should return same rows, difference is only `loc` and one `()`

Comment: `df_merged=df_merged.loc[df_merged['date1']==int(date_month)]` assign it back